# Which communication protocal should be used for a low speed internet connection

Tags: sockets, tcp, client-server, communication

I am in process of developing a game software based on Client-Server architecture. Here the game/client communicates with a remote server for fetching the various input parameters stored on the server which are required for playing the game. This process occurs every 5 minutes. The client machines are situated in an area with very slow internet connection. What would/should be a preferred connection/communication protocol I should use ? (HTTP, TCP-Sockets) or any other.

My primary aim is to reduce the bandwidth consumption and also faster response so that the game keeps on running smoothly even at low internet speed.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP and TCP are fundamentally different protocols as they operate on different layers. HTTP is an application layer that operates on top of a transport layer protocol such as TCP.

To shed unneeded information that gets transferred over HTTP (the HTTP headers), you should probably create your own application layer protocol that works on top of an [existing transport layer protocol such as TCP or UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer).

However, without getting more information about how you are coding the game and what kind of information you wish to transfer, it's difficult to give a more specific answer.

You might want to look into the library [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/index.html), which does a good job of handling the application layer protocol for you.

Comment: Hello Mathias-S. Thank you for your reply. The game basically fetches the user account information and available points to play the game and etc. So I would like to know if I should create a client-server Socket or HTTP based API's call mechanism for this ? As many location where the game is supposed to be deployed have very slow Internet connection speed.

Comment: A client-server Socket would need to transfer less information than HTTP. I don't know which language you are using, but trying to minimize the number of bytes you need to send is the way to go: Shed unnecessary headers (HTTP), make your own protocol where you only send the needed bits, i.e. if the available points are integers, determine how big ints you need (16 bits? 24 bits? 32 bits?) and send the numbers as bytes instead of characters (as you probably would with HTTP), i.e. sending 10000 through text takes 5 bytes, sending it as a 16 bit number requires 2 bytes.

Comment: Also, you might want to look into [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) which handles this for you. Then you would still need to code the socket communication (to avoid HTTP, see above), but at least you'd be able to minimize the data you need to transfer without too much work.

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot Mathias-S for your time. Its of great help.